# What is the best way for pooling httpclient?

Tags: java, pool

My main goal is for pooling a httpclient in silent or somehow, and i'd like to call a method to give me a httpclient...because i think its too resource usage for every rest call add a new httpclient instance and set the things and so on...is there best practice for it?

Comment: Please, read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and make appropriate changes to your question.

Comment: https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/tutorial/html/connmgmt.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you refer to `Apache` HTTP client then you may follow the steps below:

1. Initiate `Apache` HTTP client only once, since it is thread safe you can safely reuse it. If you use Spring then it should be safe to store it in the Spring Context as a Bean. See following [link](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/performance.html) for the thread-safety.
2. Despite the fact that HTTP client instance itself is not pooled (since you gonna use single instance of it) what you can do to increase the performance is configuring pooled connection manager on the HTTP client. See following [link](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/tutorial/html/connmgmt.html) for the details.
   (search for the 'Pooling connection manager' on that page) . The actual code should be something similar to the snippet bellow :

```java
PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager cm = new PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager();
// Increase max total connection to 200
cm.setMaxTotal(200);
// Increase default max connection per route to 20
cm.setDefaultMaxPerRoute(20);
// Increase max connections for localhost:80 to 50
HttpHost localhost = new HttpHost("localhost", 80);
cm.setMaxPerRoute(new HttpRoute(localhost), 50);

CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.custom()
        .setConnectionManager(cm)
        .build();
```

Hope this helps .